# Slow reaction with scroll event

Tags: jquery

I have a header element at the top of the page with a menu. When I scroll down, the header animates to a lower height. And when I scroll up and reach the top, the header animates to it's original size.

but it's not working perfect. Sometimes it takes two seconds before something happens. Especially when I scroll back upwards and have reach the top. Is there a way to improve this code for better performance?

```
// Scroll show menu
$(window).scroll(function(){
    scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPosition >= 150) {
        $("header").animate({
            height: '65px'
        }); 
    }

    if (scrollPosition <= 100) {
        $("header").animate({
            height: '130px'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: is better to use Css for animation, when using animate() it used by javascript, is not so efficient...

Comment: where "using css for animation" means to use the "transition" statement inside css rules.

Comment: @Proxytype OK, would you be kind a make an answer with some simple code to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `scroll` event fires once for every pixel that is scrolled. Therefore if you scroll down 500px you're adding 350 animations to the queue.

To prevent this you can use `stop()` to clear any existing animations in the queue. Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPosition >= 150) {
        $("header").stop().animate({
            height: '65px'
        }); 
    }

    if (scrollPosition <= 100) {
        $("header").stop().animate({
            height: '130px'
        });
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mbwg9j48/)

A cleaner solution, as suggested by @Proxytype is to use CSS transitions and `addClass` and `removeClass` with jQuery:

```css
header {
    height: 130px;
    transition: height 0.3s;
}
header.small {
    height: 65px;
}
```

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
     $("header")[scrollPosition >= 150 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('small');
});
```

The last line of the above is a condensed version of this logic:

```
if (scrollPosition >= 150) {
    $('#header').addClass('small');
}
else {
    $('#header').removeClass('small');
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mbwg9j48/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but when I added the .stop nothing happend at all with the animations! What could be wrong?

Comment: That's odd. As you can see from the fiddle example, it should work. Try the CSS method though, as it's more succinct and a better separation of concerns anyway.

Comment: The CSS alternative looks nice in fiddle. But I'm not sure I follow and understand the third line in the jQuery part. It's the [ ] I haven't seen those inside jQuery before. Is this some kind on ternary operator? Could it be simplified? Please explain! :)

Comment: I added an explanation of it to the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

is better to use CSS3 is more efficient then JavaScript, for exmaple:

```
$('#dd').css("transition-duration", 0.2 + "s");
$('#dd').css("-webkit-transition-duration", 0.2 + "s");
$('#dd').css("transform", "translate3d(" + 30 + "px,0,0)");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6c2mhuwd/